# How do you hide the Presentation Tools in Powerpoint 2008?

Tags: macos, microsoft-powerpoint

When showing a slideshow the presenter tools appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set your display preference arrangement to "mirrored" the tools will not appear.  But if you have 2 separate monitors not mirroring there is no way to hide the presenter tools.

Answer (score 1):

The ONLY way I found to hide presenter tools in Powerpoint 2010, Mac version is this...

Go to the top menu and choose "Slide Show", go down to and choose SET UP SHOW. click the show type as "Browsed by Individual (window)". this will allow you to use your second display to view, and work in other programs, instead of having the Presenter Tools take over both of your monitors.