# Is there a way to move or remove the navigation buttons during a Powerpoint Presentation?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

During a Microsoft Powerpoint presentation, when you touch the screen of a touch-screen or pen-enabled device, these navigation/inking options appear in the bottom-left of your presentation:

[image]

1. Can these overlay buttons be moved so that they don't obstruct content you want visible (like my site icon in the image above)?
2. Can these overlay buttons be removed / disabled entirely?

If so, how? =).

*(I'm using Microsoft Office 2013, but I've seen these appear in other versions)*

Comment: This question [was asked and sort of answered nine years ago](https://superuser.com/questions/243759/how-do-you-hide-the-presentation-tools-in-powerpoint-2008) regarding PowerPoint 2008. I'm hoping there is a better answer for more recent versions of PowerPoint.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about 2013 but in later versions:

File | Options | Advanced
Under Slide Show, remove the check next to "Show popup toolbar"

Comment: When I checked, it was already disabled. I checked it and did a slide show, and honestly didn't see anything different. I re-un-checked it, and then restarted powerpoint, did a presentation, and the button overlay still pops up the moment I touch my laptop screen. I'm wondering if it's a result of some sort of touch options instead of slide show options.

Comment: @Eddie Touch options ... good call. At the top left of the PPT screen, on the title bar, there's a series of icons: File, Re-do, etc. Click the rightmost icon and choose "Touch/Mouse Mode" on the dropdown.  See if switching between touch and mouse mode helps. Let us know one way or the other, please!

Comment: Thanks Steve!  Currently it is set to "Mouse Mode". It seems switching to touch mode simply increases the button size of the items on the ribbon.  After further testing, it seems it is specifically inking/annotation that makes the buttons pop up during the presentation. I can start the presentation and move forward/back with arrows, even with swiping on the screen with my finger... but as soon as I hit CTRL+P *and* start drawing on the screen, the overlay buttons pop up.

Comment: Weird ... I can't think of any reason why that would be logically necessary.  A bug, perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone with a Apple Mac the location is different.
PowerPoint Menu At top of the screen
-> Preferences -> Slide Show -> Slide Show Navigation -> [No Slide Show controls]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the steps below：

1.Set Up Slide Show

2.Check Browsed at the Kiosk (full screen)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the Screen Shot =).  So, that works in the sense that it gets rid of the buttons, but then I can't move the slides forward with my clicker / arrows, nor can I use any annotations on the screen using CTRL+P shortcut (for pen).